# How to use transformations in pint package correctly?

Tags: python, pint

I am working on a project involving natural gas and want to be able to convert between volume, mass and energy using provided densities.
I have the following code python, using the [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io) package:

```py
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

ureg.define('Sm3 = m^3')  # cubic meter of gas at given temperature and pressure 
NG_DENS = 0.8 * ureg('kg/Sm3')                # density
NG_SE = 50 * ureg('MJ/kg')                    # specific energy (energy per mass)
NG_ED = (NG_SE * NG_DENS).to_reduced_units()  # energy density (energy per volume)

ng = pint.Context('ngas')
ng.add_transformation('[volume]', '[mass]', lambda ureg, x: x * NG_DENS)
ng.add_transformation('[mass]', '[energy]', lambda ureg, x: x * NG_SE)
ureg.add_context(ng)

print(f"{ureg('1 Sm3').to('kg', 'ngas') = }")
print(f"{ureg('1 Sm3').to('MJ', 'ngas') = }")
print(f"{ureg('1 Sm3/s').to('MJ/s', 'ngas') = }")
print(f"{ureg('1 Sm3/s').to('MW', 'ngas') = }")
```

The first two `print` lines work, showing that the transformations are transitive (we define conversions from volume to mass and mass to energy, so it is also possible to transform volume to energy). Hence, I do not actually need `NG_ED`.

However, for the last two lines to work I have to add *one* of the following transformations to the definition of context `ng`:

```py
ng.add_transformation('[volume]/[time]', '[energy]/[time]', lambda ureg, x: x * NG_ED)
ng.add_transformation('[volume]/[time]', '[power]', lambda ureg, x: x * NG_ED)
```

And if I wanted to convert `[mass]/[time]` to `[power]`, I would have to add that transformation as well.

Why doesn't `pint` figure this out? And, in general, what kind of relationships can I expect `pint` to deduce self and what has to be specified?

Or am I using the library wrong, i.e., is there a better way to achieve these transformations?

I am using `pint` 0.19.2 on python 3.9.1 on Windows.

Comment: I was facing similar challenges, and I could only make it work by adding transformations manually until all needed paths were satisfied.  I suspect it works great for transformations that only require units with positive dimensionalities.  Once there are units in the denominator, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer you directly, but currently, i am playing with a pint, I even make a web-app universal converter using Streamlit and pint,

Here is the code in my GitHub repo

in my repo, i use dimensionality method to know similar units, if i have more than one unit i define a new unit, say unit_3 =unit_1/unit_2, and then check unit_3 dimensionality and compare it to all units in pint registry for conversion

here is my git hub repo

https://github.com/Amsamms/Unit-Converter.git